# Please help with derivatives exercise?

Tags: derivatives, polynomials

SAULA_TV manufactures middle-size TVs. The quantity $x$ of these TVs demanded each week is related to the wholesale unit price $p$ by equation
$$p=-0,006x+180.$$
The weekly total cost incurred by the factory for producing $x$ units is
$$TC(x)=0,000002x^3-0,02x^2+120x+60000$$
euros. Because of
technological requirements the factory can’t produce less than $4000$, and more than $10000$ TVs per week. What should be the level of production per week so that one additionally produced TV would
generate $32,5$ euros of profit? I tried to use Profit formula and everything else I had in my records , but I can't get the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I don't know much about specific profit formulas; that sounds awfully close to economics, and I am but a mathematician. Thankfully we don't need economics to figure this out.

Now, because this smells like a homework problem and not just an excercise you are doing for self improvement, you are probably not going to get a solution from anyone on the site. What people will give you, however, is some insight into what you can do.

We want to say something about profit. Roughly speaking, profit is price times demand minus cost. If we assume that we produce exactly the demand, then we can begin to solve this problem by turning it on it's head; let's not dictate production by price, but price by production. Let me explain further.

So, we know that we can only produce between 4000 and 10000 units. This means that I can choose $x$ to be anything I want in the range $[4000,10000]$. This is my independent variable. The price $p(x)$ is secretly a function of this variable. The cost $TC(x)$ is a function of this variable. The profit is now also a function of this variable; write this down explicitly!

Once we have a formula for the profit $P(x)$ in terms of the quantity of production $x$, we can go back and reread the question in this new language; what should $x$ be equal to if we want $\frac{dP(x)}{dx}=32.5$?

Does this help you?

Comment: First of all, yes it's from economics and this theme is really hard for me .... So, P(x)= -0,00002x^3+0,014x^2+60x-60000 I understand everything to this point , but I don't know what to do next :/

Comment: Have you taken a calculus course yet? My final two sentences basically lay out exactly what to do, assuming you are familiar with the notation.